# Suppose $p$ is a degree $3$ polynomial such that $p(0)=1$, $p(1)=2$, and $p(2)=5$. Which one of the following cannot equall $p(3)?$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

**TIFR GS-2018- PhD Screening Test.**

> Suppose $p$ is a degree $3$ polynomial such that $p(0)=1$, $p(1)=2$,
>   and $p(2)=5$. Which one of the following cannot equall $p(3)?$
>
> (A)$0$
>
> (B)$2$
>
> (C)$6$
>
> (D)$10$

Suppose $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

$$p(0)=1 \implies d=1$$

$$p(1)=2 \implies a+b+c=1$$

$$p(2)=5 \implies 8a+4b+2c=4$$

solving, $b=1-\frac{3}{2}c$ and $a=c$

then our equation becomes 
$p(x)=cx^3+(1-\frac{3}{2}c)x^2+cx+1.$

I tried to find $p(3)=27c+(1-\frac{3}{2}c)9+3c+1.$

I don't know how to eliminate the option. Please help me.

Comment: Are coefficients supposed to be integers? Is the question which one can be $p(3)?

Comment: You should have $c=2a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is d) because $c=2a$ and if $a=0$ then it is not a 3. degree polynomial.

Comment: you are right. so simple. Thank you very much :). I was very near. I couldn't judge :'(

Answer (score 2):

*PhD screening test*? That's a question for undergraduates, at most. Let $\delta$ be the forward difference operator, $(\delta p)(x)=p(x+1)-p(x)$. If $\deg p\geq 1$ we have $\deg(\delta p) = \deg p-1$, hence for any polynomial $p$ with degree $=3$ we have $\delta^4 p = 0$ but $\delta^3 p=c\neq 0$.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc}p(x) && 1 && 2 && 5 && y\\\delta p(x) &&& 1 && 3 &&y-5\\\delta^2 p(x) &&&& 2 && y-8 \\ \delta^3 p(x) &&&&& y-10 &&  \end{array} $$
If we do not want $\delta^3 p$ to vanish, $y=p(3)$ has to be different from $10$.
No explicit interpolation is needed.

Comment: Yes. It seems like below P.G level question. But when I reached the last equation, I expected $c$ to have some complex value?But It was a linear, equation. I had the prejudice that every linear equation has the solution.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan: I honestly do not understand your issue. If $p(x)$ has real values, $\delta p(x)$ has real values and so on. But what I wrote still makes sense if $p(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$: if $\deg p=3$, $(\delta^3 p)(x)$ is a non-zero constant.

Comment: sorry! Thank you very much @JackD'Aurizio. It was a PhD Screening test question(Round I)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That is neatly done.

Answer (score 0):

$$p(x)-x^2-1=cx(x-1)(x-2)$$
Rest you can do.

Comment: This is not true. $p(x)=Ax(x-1)(x-2)+x^2+1$ is the most general form.

Comment: I was just editing that. I assumed a monic polynomial at first.

Comment: Something is probably wrong with the OP question, as this shows that $p(3)=10+6c$ can be any number. It seems that @MarkBennet comment to the question corrects this.

Comment: Yeah, there must be the condition that the coefficients are integers.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate 10.

This is clearly a very simple polynomial fitting exercise. If you fit a third order to polynomial to x = [0 1 2 3] and y = [ 1, 2, 5, p(3)] where p(3) is either 0,2,6, or 10, you get the following values for [a, b, c, d]:

0: [ -5/3   6  -10/3   1]

2: [ -5/3   5  -8/3    1]

6: [ -2/3   3  -4/3    1]

10:[   0    1    0     1]

The solution for p(3) = 10, is no longer a third order polynomial, and therefore does not met the specification that p be a third order polynomial, unless one includes third order polynomials with the x^3 coefficient = 0. I cannot think of any other rationale for eliminating any of the solutions.

A subtle point: Your final equation in p(x) and c is clearly just a linear equation in c, given a value of p(x). For p(x) = 10, c = 0.  But if c = 0 then the equations with p(1) and p(2) reduce to:

p(1) =  2 =>  a + b = 1,

p(2) = 5 =>  4a + 4b = 4

and are no longer linearly independent. But we know that setting a to 0 and b to 1 provides a valid solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use MathJax for math formatting- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score -2):

Option d is correct because  as we solving we get that if $p(3)=10$ then $a=0$ and this is not possible in $3$<sup>rd</sup> degree polynomial.