# Cardinality of the set of multiple-representation decimals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, binary, decimal-expansion

> The set of real numbers in the open interval $(0,1)$ which have more
>   than one decimal expansion is
>
> (A) Empty
>
> (B)non-empty but finite
>
> (C)Countably infinite
>
> (D)uncountable

I know that, $$\frac{1}{10}=.10000...=.0999999...$$
              $$\frac{1}{10}=.010000...=.099999...$$
              $$ \frac{1}{100}=.0010000...=.0099999...$$

$$...$$

$$\frac{1}{10^n}$$ has also the two binary representation.

I think answer is (C). Am I correct? How do I prove it rigorously. Please help me.

**When I was doing the above question, this question came in to mind.**

> I have question that The set of real numbers in the open interval
>   $(0,1)$ which have more than one binary expansion is
>
> (A) Empty
>
> (B)non-empty but finite
>
> (C)Countably infinite
>
> (D)uncountable

I think the elements of the form $\frac{1}{2^n}$ has two binary expansion in $(0,1)$ . but I couldn't give the rigorous proof. Please help me.

Comment: By the way ,Maneesh, I heard this question from somebody else yesterday. I get the feeling it has appeared in a competitive exam recently.

Comment: yes. TIFR GS 2018

Comment: Exam held yesterday. I feel to mark (C). But due to lack of confidence, i didn't mark ;'(

Comment: That is unfortunate, now you cannot do much about it. However, if there are any other questions from that exam, you may post them as well. But of course , +1.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560250/let-a-be-a-set-of-all-continuous-functions-f0-1-to-mathbb-r-cup-0

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560171/let-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-be-continuous-then-which-of-the-following-state

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560091/suppose-p-is-a-degree-3-polynomial-such-that-p0-1-p1-2-and-p2-5

Comment: I will ask in future. I could solve 23 questions only out of 40 in 2 hours. @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Very nice. I shall look forward to these!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In any base $b$, using $h$ to denote the highest possible digit, all the numbers in $(0,1)$ that have more than one representation have the form
$$0.xxx\dots p000\ldots=0.xxx\dots qhhh\dots$$
where $p\ne0$ and $q=p-1$. In other words, they have a terminating expansion.

Thus the set of all such numbers is countably infinite by the following bijection between the terminating expansions and the positive integers:
$$(0.x_1x_2\dots x_k)_b\to(x_k\dots x_2x_1)_b$$
(C) is correct for both questions.

Answer (score 10):

> A number has more than one decimal expansion if and only if it has terminating decimal expansion.

To see this, if it does terminate, then if it goes like $\overline{a_1\cdots a_n . b_1\cdots b_n}$ then an alternating decimal expansion is also $\overline{a_1\cdots a_n.b_1\cdots b_{n-1} 999...}$

On the other hand, any non-terminating decimal expansion is determined uniquely, for example by repeated long division, which does not terminate and therefore does not give us room to introduce the chain of $9$s, as done in the terminating case.

Hence, the set of such real numbers actually is countable.

A similar argument can be given for the binary case, with the same conclusion.